# PHP5, if, elseif, if with preg_replace not working

Tags: php, preg-match

I tried to look on here as to why this code is not working, got no where and now I'm hoping someone can help me out.

```
function validateData($string) {
    if (empty($string)) {
        return 'error';
    } elseif (strlen($string) <= 1) {
        return 'error';
    } elseif (preg_match('[a-zA-Z0-9]+\ ?', $string)) {
        return 'error';
    } else {
        return 'normal';
    }
}
```

When I execute the above code, using:

```
echo validateData('Test');
echo validateData('Test!');
```

These both echo 'normal'.. however, the second example contains the '!' in the string and should return 'error' because of the preg_match statement in the above code.

**Achievement Objective. Check a string to make sure that it is not EMPTY, that it is longer than 1 character and only contains a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or a space. So no special characters.**

Thank you very much in advance to all answers, I really appreciate it!

Ken

Comment: your regex is wrong, it will return true if any alphanumeric character is present.

Comment: cryptic, care to elaborate then how I can reach my objective that I wrote in bold above?

Comment: use `!preg_match(pattern,$string)`, check my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string is empty, it will be equal to 0 when you ask for it's string length, therefore testing empty($string) is useless since it is covered by the second test.

Using a regex adds complexity without benefit here, there is a dedicated function to return true or false for alphanumeric string: ctype_alnum($string)

Your function can just be:

```
function validateData($string) {
    return (strlen($string) <= 1 || !ctype_alnum($string)) ? 'error' : 'normal';
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but, by default a lot of distributions, using their package management system, have ctype functionality off by default.

Comment: I don't think this is true today. Debian stable and Ubuntu have it, just these 2 distros and their derivatives probably make the bulk of PHP servers. A quick search on google does not show recent issues with Ctype not being activated by default. Do you have a distro in mind that would have deactivated ctype?

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern should look like this:

```
preg_match('/([^a-zA-Z0-9 ])+/', $string);
```

The `^` symbol is used to negate a character set.

Answer (score 1):

use `!preg_match(pattern,$string)`, if you need to validate strings which contains spaces, then use following, otherwise, remove `\s` from `preg_match` pattern

```
 function validateData($string) {
    if (empty($string)) {
         return 'error';
    } elseif (strlen($string) <= 1) {
         return 'error';
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/',  $string)) {
         return 'error';
    } else {
       return 'normal';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\ ?/', $string)
```

Comment: danc, using this still errors. Now both instances of my validateData() examples return 'error'

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`preg_match('[a-zA-Z0-9]+\ ?', $string)`

with

`preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', $string)`